# I want to disable Jquery tablednd

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Hi i have used jquery tablednd. I have written a function which initializes the tablednd to a table

But i want to know if there is any option of disabling the tablednd...??

Answer (score 6):

I was able to disable the tableDnD by calling the following function:

```
function tableDragAndDropDisable(cssID){
    $(cssID + " tr").addClass("nodrag nodrop");
}

// sample usage
tableDragAndDropDisable("#sortable_table");
```

This will add the "nodrag nodrop" classes to each row of the table with the given ID (`cssID`) - effectively disabling the table of its sorting ability.

Comment: Excellent!  (:  Saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I think the exact way to disable tableDnd show be: remove the 'mousedown' bind of td.

So the example is:

html:

```
<table id="first-table"> ..... </table>
<table id="second-table"> ..... </table>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
// disable first table
jQuery("#first-table td").unbind("mousedown");

// enable second table
jQuery("#second-table").removeclass("nodrag nodrop").tableDnD();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the cssclasses nodrop and nodrag

```
rows.removeClass('nodrop nodrag');
```

where rows are the table rows

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I have two tables. On the click of one hyperlink I want to disable the first table and show the 2nd table with tablednd. Can you tell me how to write the function for the same. It will be really helpful... :) Thanks in advance :)